# What is ADF Mapping data flow expression language?

Tags: azure, el, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data factory Mapping data flow and i just noticed that in Mapping data flow Expression Builder the  Expression i build is actually in expression language.

My client ask about that expression language, "Is it `json` or `SQL`?"
So what is the answer will be? 
It is just  expression language or anything else?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the "expression language", it's not a kind of language like `json` or `SQL`.

Data Factory doesn't named for the expression, just call it "expression language".

[image: expression language]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon for your response,

Answer (score 2):

The expressions that you build in the Expression Builder are made up of the "high order" functions exposed to the transformations in the ADF Data Flow UI. The full functions list is here: https://aka.ms/dataflowexpressions.

Comment: Not to be confused with ADF dynamic content expressions which seem to be slightly different https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/how-to-expression-language-functions.md